# How can you intercept and modify a HTTP response from a WebView (Mac)?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, webview, inject

I would like to intercept a resource response from an HTTP request that is downloaded as an additional resource from a page that is currently being loaded. I am specifically trying to do this to a JavaScript file from an `iframe` that is being requested, before it is loaded into memory from the response.  This means that I cannot execute JavaScript from the web view to directly modify the DOM in the `iframe`.

Once intercepted, I would like to attach my own logic to it. This is a classic man-in-the-middle attack, except that I am attaching my own logic to it before rendering the request into the web view.

Right now I am staring at the `WebResourceLoadDelegate` protocol but I cannot find any documentation that leads to allowing me modify the incoming response.